# Functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: analysis, functions

Can mathematical functions have variable (arbitrarily large) number of arguments? If not, which mathematical objects have this property?

Comment: You can use functions as arguments for functions. You can also use sets.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise?

Comment: I cannot understand, what is not precise in my question

Comment: A function has a prescribed domain. Therefore, if I understand what you're trying to ask, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing prevents you to use complicated domain sets for the definition of a function, e.g. for [formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) the definition
$$
L^* = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty L^k
$$
is common, where $*$ is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

So you might define $\mathbb{R}^*$ in a similar way, which consists of all tuples with finite dimension, although I can not remember seeing it used.

This would cover all cases of finite many variables.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking there is always only one argument (that is an element of the domain of the function). You can put elements in tuples e.g. $(x,y,z)$ so it seems there are many arguments and even leave out the paranthesis i.e $f(x,y,z)$. But stricly speaking a function has a domain (a set where it is defined) and it's defined at those points only. Of course you can have "anything" in that set, for example tuples (of all possible sizes even infinite lenght) of real numbers.